# VBScript writing to file error

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error

I've coded a script that has the basic function of creating a .txt file and then writing some text into it. But whenever I run it I get;

`Script: F\Known.vbs
    Line: 17
    Char:1
    Error: Permission denied
    Code: 800A0046
    Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error`

My code goes as such;

`Option Explicit
    Dim objFSO, objFSOText, objFolder, r, objFile
    Dim strDirectory, strFile
    Dim objNetwork
    do
    randomize
    r = int(rnd*91372183) + 1
    strDirectory = "C:\Users\" & CreateObject("Wscript.Network").UserName & "\Desktop"
    strFile = "\" & r & ".txt"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
    Const ReadOnly = 1
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strDirectory & strFile)
    objFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, ForWriting)
    objFile.Write "f672f7fd12d6wf6df26df6f26dfs6f6qf67wqqf6dfw6f16fw76df61f62fd"
    objFile.WriteBlankLines(1)
    loop`

I have looked at other questions of a similar nature, trying to add read-write attributes, etc. but none have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your script with administrative privileges .
To do so **open command prompt as administrator** and navigate to the directory where the script is contained in and then run the following command

```
>cscript {Your script name}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open the 'strDirectory & strFile'-file a second time with

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, ForWriting)
```

in line 17 after you opened it in line 11 with

```
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
```

Evidence:

```
>> Set f = oFS.CreateTextFile("x")
>> Set f = oFS.OpenTextFile("x", 2)
>>
Error Number:       70
Error Description:  Erlaubnis verweigert.
>>
```

The other parts of your script are a mess (Randomize and Const in a loop, variables not used, bad attempts to roll your own versions of standard methods), so you should **read** the docs and **plan** before you write your next lines of code.